# Failed to parse _doc type: Mapping errors in Elasticsearch 7.x

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying for creating index in elasticsearch by using following query

```
PUT company
{
  "mappings": {
    "employees": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "birth": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "addr": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "number_of_replicas": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Getting the following error after executing query in the Kibana dash board the issue 
I think the issue regarding weather I am giving some wrong parameters:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [employees : {properties={name={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, birth={type=date}, id={type=long}, addr={type=text}}}]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [employees : {properties={name={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, birth={type=date}, id={type=long}, addr={type=text}}}]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [employees : {properties={name={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, birth={type=date}, id={type=long}, addr={type=text}}}]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this document:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html

Mapping types have been deprecated from Elasticsearch version 7.x. You can put your mappings without mentioning `_doc` also.

```
PUT company
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "birth": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "addr": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
     "index": {
         "number_of_shards": "5",
         "number_of_replicas": "1"
     }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "shards_acknowledged" : true,
  "index" : "company"
}
```

Verify:

```
GET company/_mapping
```

Output:

```
{
  "company" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "addr" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "birth" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps, much easier to understand and will avoid confusion around the `_doc` property.

Answer (score 0):

Its because ES >= 7.0 removed support for mapping types, so you can try this way using custom type `_doc` instead of `employee` type. See More: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html

```
PUT company
{
"mappings": {
"_doc": {
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "birth": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "addr": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
 }
},
"settings": {
 "index": {
  "number_of_shards": "5",
  "number_of_replicas": "1"
  }
 }
}
```